# Xcode lost all themes over night

Tags: xcode, color-scheme

I've no clue at all what could have happened, but Xcode lost all the theme over night. I didn't install a new update. I just shutdown my Mac yesterday evening and today every single theme except the standard ones is gone.

I checked the directory:
***~/Library/Application Support/Xcode/Color Themes***
and all themes are still available. I tried removing all but one that is fairly new to check if there is a problem with one of them. But it didn't help.

I also rebootet my Mac. I've no clue what happened?

Yesterday morning I created a new user on this Mac which has no admin privileges but is set as a developer via this terminal command:

```
sudo dscl . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership <username>
```

Could this be the cause?

Comment: I updated XCode today and the problem is still there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Alcatraz](https://mneorr.github.io/Alcatraz) and solve your issues once forever :)

Comment: Actually this sounds pretty interesting. Thanks for the tipp. I'll check it out.